# How to save a search criteria?

Tags: contacts, groups, search

is there a way to save the search criteria from a 'search builder' or 'advanced search' for future use without making it a smart group? TIA

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but there is some support for bookmarking a url for certain types of searches:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching-url-support/

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth using the data processor extension? I do for more complex advanced searches that I want to save for easy access.